# Convert Database dates to unix timestamp

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, unix-timestamp

I got an array from the database like this:

```
array
(
[section] => colours
[dd] => 1
[mm] => 3
[yy] => 13
[name] => red
)
array
(
[section] => colours
[dd] => 15
[mm] => 3
[yy] => 13
[name] => green
)
array
(
[section] => colours
[dd] => 15
[mm] => 3
[yy] => 13
[name] => blue
)
```

Now I want to convert every colours dates (dd/mm/yy) into unix timestamp so that I can compare it later with current timestamp.

Any suggestions?? thanks in advance

Comment: [`mktime()`](http://php.net/mktime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strtotime($data['dd'].'-'.$data['mm'].'-'.$data['yy']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `strtotime`, for example:

```
<?php

$dates = array(
    array(
        'section' => 'colours',
        'dd' => 1,
        'mm' => 3,
        'yy' => 13,
        'name' => 'red',
    ),
    array(
        'section' => 'colours',
        'dd' => 15,
        'mm' => 3,
        'yy' => 13,
        'name' => 'green',
    ),
    array(
        'section' => 'colours',
        'dd' => 15,
        'mm' => 3,
        'yy' => 13,
        'name' => 'blue',
    ),
);


for ($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++) {
    $dates[$i]['timestamp'] = strtotime('20' . $dates[$i]['yy'] . '-' . $dates[$i]['mm'] . '-' . $dates[$i]['dd']);
}

print_r($dates);
```

Produces the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [section] => colours
            [dd] => 1
            [mm] => 3
            [yy] => 13
            [name] => red
            [timestamp] => 1362092400
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [section] => colours
            [dd] => 15
            [mm] => 3
            [yy] => 13
            [name] => green
            [timestamp] => 1363302000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [section] => colours
            [dd] => 15
            [mm] => 3
            [yy] => 13
            [name] => blue
            [timestamp] => 1363302000
        )

)
```